# How can I use the data from reverseGeocodeLocation in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

EDIT SOLUTION: As I suspected `reverseGeocodeLocation` is asynchronous so I had to use

```
dispatch_async(
            dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.newAddress = address
        })
```

You also have to wait until the newAddress variable gets updated to use it. There is some lag but it's typical time, about a second if that.

ORIGINAL:

I'm trying to use the String from `CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation` to send to another view when an annotation on the map is pressed. However the handler exists in a closure and its `Void in`. I've tried `String in` but that doesn't go along with the protocol.

Is there a way I can use the data from the closure?

Code for reverse geocoding

```
 func getReversedGeocodeLocation(){
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(newMeetupLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in


        if error != nil {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks != nil {
            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0]
                self.name = pm.name! + "-" + pm.thoroughfare!
            }

        }
        else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you post more of your code? Are you trying to send a String of the address?

Comment: added the code. I just need to find out how to get data out of a closure. I want to be able to use the string of the address.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are trying to achieve ?

```
    func getReversedGeocodeLocation(){
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(newMeetupLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in


            if error != nil {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks != nil {
                if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                    let pm = placemarks![0]
                    let myAddress = pm.name! + "-" + pm.thoroughfare!
                    // just pass the address along, ie
                    self.newAddressFromGeocode(myAddress)
                }

            }
            else {
                print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
            }
        })
    }

    func newAddressFromGeocode(address:String) {
        print(address)
        // this is called from the completion handler
        // do what you like here ie perform a segue and pass the string along
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
// add a variable outside the function. Once this is filled with the address you can pass it in your prepareForSegue
 var addresssFromPlacemark = ""

 func getReversedGeocodeLocation(){
    CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(newMeetupLocation, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in


        if error != nil {
            print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
            return
        }

        if placemarks != nil {
            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let placemark = placemarks![0]
                var line = ""

                // Format placemark into a string
                line.addText(placemark.name)
                line.addText(placemark.subThoroughfare, withSeparator: ", ")
                if placemark.subThoroughfare != nil {
                line.addText(placemark.thoroughfare, withSeparator: " ")
                } else {
                line.addText(placemark.thoroughfare, withSeparator: ", ")
                }
                line.addText(placemark.locality, withSeparator: ", ")
                line.addText(placemark.administrativeArea, withSeparator: ", ")
                line.addText(placemark.postalCode, withSeparator: ", ")
                line.addText(placemark.country, withSeparator: ", ")
                self.addressFromPlacemark = line
            }

        }
        else {
            print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: I've tried changing a variable from within the closure but it doesn't update. Something to do with it being asynchronous

Comment: Are you sure the code is being called? Add print("Made it this far") under your code let pm = placemarks![0]

Comment: Yeah I'm able to print within the closure, but that's as far as it goes. Even doing the method from the other poster where I call a method it doesn't update.

Comment: using the code I posted if you put print("\\(self.addressFromPlacemark)") after self.addressFromPlacemark = line does it print the address?